# FatalErrorException in line 52: syntax error, unexpected 'height' (T_STRING)

Tags: html, css, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I am trying to create an image route, meaning, using an image for a route.  This is the update link I'm trying to create but it keeps giving this error:

```
FatalErrorException in fdda73edfe1d1362826e9383e141e71a line 52:
syntax error, unexpected 'height' (T_STRING)
```

Maybe the formatting of css is what it does not understand. 
This is the code:

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('updateUserContact', '<img style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain' src="' . asset('images/add.png') . '"/>', contacts->id) !!}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('updateUserContact', '<img style="height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain" src="' . asset('images/add.png') . '"/>', contacts->id) !!}
```

You used single quote, which was ending the string/parameter early

Comment: ```FatalErrorException in fdda73edfe1d1362826e9383e141e71a line 52:
syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)``` It has resulted to the above error code. Appreciate your support.

Comment: Read the error dude it's to do with `contacts->id`. The code above should fix your original problem. If you have a problem with that code you will need to ask a separate question and mark this as accepted as it's fixed your original issue